# Excel: How to concatenate cells following a pattern? (cells are not in the same row!)

Tags: excel, vba, function, powerquery, offset

I have the following excel:

[image]

expected results:

[image]

I have tried power query, excel functions but I can't get the result that I need.

Do you think that is it possible to achieve that without vba?

Thank you!

Comment: What Excel version do you have?

Comment: How do you define if lvl3 concatenates with the numbers below or not?

Comment: Hi Ricardo, I'm using Office 365 (16.0.12527.21378) 32-bits.

Comment: It would be concatenated with the elements of the next level:

Comment: What is logic to exclude `WSP` from expected result?

Comment: Hi Arun, I tried with Text join, It's a nice approach! Really appreciate it. I did some tests and I have some issues: https://gyazo.com/14a92425437c14f40887b0ff24a62035. I'll play around a bit more.

I don't want to exclude WSP. Please have a look to the image. We're defining a hierarchy, some of the levels have elements inside, some others levels not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT 2: Based on the file on your comment, I refactored the formula to work with blanks

Based on this cells layout:

[image]

Use this formula:

```
=TEXTJOIN("-",TRUE,
    IFERROR(INDEX(M$3:M3,MAX((M$3:M3<>"")*(ROW(M$3:M3)))-ROW(M$3)+1),""),
    IFERROR(IF(MAX((N$3:N3<>"")*(ROW(N$3:N3)))-ROW(N$3)+1<MAX((M$3:M3<>"")*(ROW(M$3:M3)))-ROW(M$3)+1,"",INDEX(N$3:N3,MAX((N$3:N3<>"")*(ROW(N$3:N3)))-ROW(N$3)+1)),""),
    IFERROR(IF(OR(MAX((O$3:O3<>"")*(ROW(O$3:O3)))-ROW(O$3)+1<MAX((M$3:M3<>"")*(ROW(M$3:M3)))-ROW(M$3)+1,MAX((O$3:O3<>"")*(ROW(O$3:O3)))-ROW(O$3)+1<MAX((N$3:N3<>"")*(ROW(N$3:N3)))-ROW(N$3)+1),"",INDEX(O$3:O3,MAX((O$3:O3<>"")*(ROW(O$3:O3)))-ROW(O$3)+1)),""),
    IF(P3<>"",IFNA(INDEX(P$3:P3,MAX((P$3:P3<>"")*(ROW(P$3:P3)))-ROW(P$3)+1),""),""))
```

EDIT 3: If you have it available, you can use the `LET` function to simplify it

```
=LET(
    a,MAX((M$3:M3<>"")*(ROW(M$3:M3)))-ROW(M$3)+1,
    b,MAX((N$3:N3<>"")*(ROW(N$3:N3)))-ROW(N$3)+1,
    c,MAX((O$3:O3<>"")*(ROW(O$3:O3)))-ROW(O$3)+1,
    d,MAX((P$3:P3<>"")*(ROW(P$3:P3)))-ROW(P$3)+1,

    TEXTJOIN("-",TRUE,
    IFERROR(INDEX(M$3:M3,a),""),
    IFERROR(IF(b<a,"",INDEX(N$3:N3,b)),""),
    IFERROR(IF(OR(c<a,c<b),"",INDEX(O$3:O3,c)),""),
    IF(P3<>"",IFNA(INDEX(P$3:P3,d),""),"")))
```

Let me know if it works for you!

Comment: I'm trying to use it same like you but I'm getting this: https://gyazo.com/32849d895e01a60aced67a06bbfefd85

Comment: Same thing. I'm replicating your sheet, same cells and columns. Please have a look: https://gyazo.com/76062df5343aad2eae036af9ea8ca3d1

Comment: Can you share your sample workbook with a onedrive link?

Comment: Yes: https://1drv.ms/x/s!Akmhm4db64ebqSvtF65R4OgBCIGt?e=AUNytG. Thank you very much!

Comment: It isn't working because you have empty strings instead of empty cells. Let me see if I can find a solution

Comment: Could you share with me your workbook? I might adapt it. Thank you !!

Comment: Please see my two EDITs ([Workbook](https://1drv.ms/x/s!ArAKssDW3T7wtLRgRQAxxhFtkMts9w?e=cvXBp0))

Comment: Hi Ricardo, your first formula is working for now (I'll need some time to understand it going through it). However, I'd prefer the second one but seems like I don't have the LET function in my Excel version and probably is the same for all the people internally here. Is that just related in the office version? I mean, a newer version would incorporate that function? I really appreciate your help!

Comment: Yes sure. Really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution

The algorithm is

```
If first column is not empty, then take value in first column
Else
    Truncate existing final code to the length corresponding to the previous column
    Append value from the current column.
```

Formula is

```
=IF(M3<>"",M3,
     LEFT(S2,FIND("|",SUBSTITUTE(S2&"-","-","|",MATCH("*",M3:Q3,0)-1))-1)
       &"-"&INDEX(M3:Q3,MATCH("*",M3:Q3,0))
  )
```

[image]

Here is a modified formula for the case where unoccupied cells contain empty strings rather than blanks:

```
=IF(M3<>"",M3,
     LEFT(S2&"-",FIND("|",SUBSTITUTE(S2&"-","-","|",INDEX(MATCH(TRUE,M3:Q3<>"",0),1)-1)))
       &INDEX(M3:Q3,INDEX(MATCH(TRUE,M3:Q3<>"",0),1))
)
```

The Index wrapper round the Match functions can be omitted, but then the formula would have to be array-entered with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>

Comment: Hi Tom, your formula looks very simple and I like it. However, I'm trying to using in my Excel Workbook but isn't work: ttps://gyazo.com/58390f02288ee1c5889915bbe16e8207. Any idea why happen this?

Comment: I noticed in the comments to @Ricardo Diaz that it looked as though you had empty strings in the cells instead of blank cells - I can post an alternative that should work in this case.

Answer (score 0):

If you could change your code column so that lvl2, lvl3, lvl4 and lvl5 are periods whenever lvl1 has a value (similar to image) then this is trivial in powerquery

[image]

The new version of your formula in N3 to do this would be similar to:

```
=IF(M3="",IF(ISBLANK(B3),"",_xlfn.XLOOKUP(B:B,lvl2_code[item description],lvl2_code[final code])),".")
```

Load the data into powerquery with data ... from table/range...

Click select all the lvl columns, right click, fill ... down...

Add column ... custom column ... with formula to concatenate all:

```
=[lvl1]&"-"&[lvl2]&"-"&[lvl3]&"-"&[lvl4]&"-"&[lvl5]
```

Right click new column, replace values, and replace **-.** with a null

File .. Close and load ... and done

```
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
#"Filled Down" = Table.FillDown(Source,{"lvl1", "lvl2", "lvl3", "lvl4", "lvl5"}),
#"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Filled Down", "final_code", each [lvl1]&"-"&[lvl2]&"-"&[lvl3]&"-"&[lvl4]&"-"&[lvl5]),
#"Replaced Value" = Table.ReplaceValue(#"Added Custom","-.","",Replacer.ReplaceText,{"final_code"})
in  #"Replaced Value"
```